# Lodash function to display multiple result into a single unique one

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, lodash

```
<span v-for="r in results" >{{ r.owner.first_name }} {{ r.owner.last_name}} </span>
```

I need to display the result of that in a single occurence only.

So with that code I would get:

```
John Doe 

John Doe 

John Doe
```

I just need to display it with just one owner:

```
John Doe
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) that is `this.results` without duplicates (assuming Lodash > 4.0.0):

```js
computed: {
  resultsUniqueNames() {
    return _.uniqBy(this.results, function (r) {
      return r.owner.first_name + r.owner.last_name;
    });
  }
}
```

And then use it like:

```html
<span v-for="r in resultsUniqueNames">{{ r.owner.first_name }} {{ r.owner.last_name}} </span>
```

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    results: [
      {owner: {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'}},
      {owner: {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'}},
      {owner: {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'}}
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    resultsUniqueNames() {
      return _.uniqBy(this.results, function(r) {
        return r.owner.first_name + r.owner.last_name;
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
span { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Using results:
  <span v-for="r in results">{{ r.owner.first_name }} {{ r.owner.last_name}} </span>
  <hr>
  Using resultsUniqueNames:
  <span v-for="r in resultsUniqueNames">{{ r.owner.first_name }} {{ r.owner.last_name}} </span>
</div>
```